# insert row when not exists and select statement uses subqueries

Tags: sql-server

I need to insert unique rows to table but don't know how to use where not exists when my Select uses subqueries for 2 columns.  Is there a way to do this?

BTW: I do have constraints on the table and duplicates can't be inserted but would like to avoid duplicate key errors.

I tried this format but due to subqueries, columns couldn't be bound.

```
INSERT dbo.DataValue(DateStamp, ItemId, Value)
SELECT DateStamp, ItemId, Value 
FROM dbo.tmp_holding_DataValue AS t
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM dbo.DataValue AS d
WHERE DateStamp = t.DateStamp
AND ItemId = t.ItemId);
```

My query:

```
insert into App.DimRequirementComponentDetail_TST 
(RequirementComponentSID, RequirementComponentDimensionSID, RequirementComponentDimensionValueSID,RequirementComponentDimensionValueText, Sta3n, ActiveFlag)  

select (select RequirementComponentSID from App.DimRequirementComponent  where name = @Measure ),   --   'PTSD PSY11' 
(select RequirementComponentDimensionSID from App.DimRequirementComponentDimension  where Name='ICD10 Diagnosis') , 
t1.ICD10SID,cast(t1.ICD10Code as varchar(max)),t1.Sta3n,'Y'--,t1.ICD10Description 
from app.DimICD10 t1 
where ICD10Code = @ICD10Code   --'F32.5'
```

Comment: for sure it can be bound, check if the columns are the same datatype

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the issue.  After much search found my problem was referencing a column just assigned in Select in the where clause.  The solution was to put the entire query in a subquery and then reference.

```
Select * From
(
        select (select RequirementComponentSID from App.DimRequirementComponent  where name = @Measure) as RequirementComponentSID,  
        (select RequirementComponentDimensionSID from App.DimRequirementComponentDimension  where Name='ICD10 Diagnosis') as RequirementComponentDimensionSID , 
        ICD10SID ,cast(ICD10Code as varchar(max)) as ICD10Code,Sta3n,'Y' as ActiveFlag
        from D01_VISN05.app.DimICD10  where ICD10Code = @ICD10Code
) RES

        Where not exists( select 1 from App.DimRequirementComponentDetail_TST  as d 
        join D01_VISN05.app.DimICD10 K on K.ICD10SID = RES.ICD10SID
        where RES.RequirementComponentSID = d.RequirementComponentSID 
        and RES.RequirementComponentDimensionSID = d.RequirementComponentDimensionSID 
        and RES.sta3n = d.sta3n 
        and RES.ICD10SID= K.ICD10SID 
        and RES.ICD10Code= K.ICD10Code 
        and RES.ActiveFlag = D.ActiveFlag
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Am I missing something or why can't you just do this?

```
INSERT INTO dbo.DataValue(DateStamp, ItemId, Value)
SELECT t.DateStamp, t.ItemId, t.Value 
FROM dbo.tmp_holding_DataValue AS t
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM dbo.DataValue AS d
                  WHERE d.DateStamp = t.DateStamp
                  AND d.ItemId = t.ItemId);
```